# Getting the menu button input on the SteamVR controller

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, steamvr

Hi2,

Does anyone know how to get the **menu** button input on the steamVR controller via C# code in Unity?

Currently I am able to get the input from the the trigger, trackpad, and grip button.

```
private void Update()
{
  if (SteamVR_Input._default.inActions.GrabGrip.GetStateDown(inputSource))
            Debug.Log("grab grip"); // the side button on the controller

  if (SteamVR_Input._default.inActions.GrabPinch.GetStateDown(inputSource))
            Debug.Log("grab pinch"); // the back button on the controller
        
  if (SteamVR_Input._default.inActions.Teleport.GetStateDown(inputSource))
            Debug.Log("teleport"); // the big middle button on the controller
}
```

[image]

any help is appreciated. ^_^

Comment: The menu button is used to open the steamvr overlay iirc. So I don't know if you can actually. My best guess is to check if you can assign an action for it in the steamvr input mapping and try it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Select in the menu 'Window -> SteamVR Input'. From there click on 'Open Binding UI'.
Your browser will open a screen where you can see this:

[image: Controller Config Page]
The red arrow points to where you can add an action for the menu button (sorry, mine is in German). Call it 'MenuClick' and make sure you save that in your private settings.
Then, in your code access it as

```
if (SteamVR_Input._default.inActions.MenuClick.GetStateDown(inputSource))
            Debug.Log("menu button pressed"); // the menu button on the controller
```